# Align the long forms of acronyms starting from same position using glossaries package

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, glossaries, acronyms

I was trying to list the acronyms used in the complete write-up. For this, i use glossaries package and followed the steps to get the required thing. I was able to get that but i get the acronyms list appearance unmanaged in terms of alignment of long form of acronyms. I just want the appearance of the list such that the starting word of long form of all acronyms lie in a vertical line (i.e. at same position) rather starting from random position.

My MWE is as below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[symbols,nopostdot,savewrites,acronym,nogroupskip,style=index]{glossaries}
\setlength\glsdescwidth{0.8\hsize}
\renewcommand\glstreepredesc{\qquad}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{fpp}{FPP}{First Peak Point}
\newacronym{spp}{SPP}{Second Peak Point}
\newacronym{tpp}{TPP}{Third Peak Point}
\newacronym{fpv}{FPV}{First Peak Value}
\newacronym{spv}{SPV}{Second Peak Value}
\newacronym{tpv}{TPV}{Third Peak Value}
\newacronym{er}{ER}{Excluded Region}
\newacronym{md}{MD}{Molecular Dynamics}
\newacronym{mc}{MC}{Monte Carlo}
\newacronym{gromacs}{GROMACS}{GROningen MAchine for Chemical Simulations}
\begin{document}
    \printglossary[type=acronym,style=tree,nonumberlist]
    \glsaddall
\end{document}
```

[image: This is what i got]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a style called `long` which does what you want.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{fpp}{FPP}{First Peak Point}
\newacronym{spp}{SPP}{Second Peak Point}
\newacronym{tpp}{TPP}{Third Peak Point}
\newacronym{fpv}{FPV}{First Peak Value}
\newacronym{spv}{SPV}{Second Peak Value}
\newacronym{tpv}{TPV}{Third Peak Value}
\newacronym{er}{ER}{Excluded Region}
\newacronym{md}{MD}{Molecular Dynamics}
\newacronym{mc}{MC}{Monte Carlo}
\newacronym{gromacs}{GROMACS}{GROningen MAchine for Chemical Simulations}

\begin{document}
    \printglossary[style=long, nonumberlist, nogroupskip]
    \glsaddall
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/202011)

Comment: I added a MWE which (I think) does answer the question...

Comment: Approved! :-)..and thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Marca85. It worked